# Calculate Bias of Parzen WIndows analytically

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-density, probability-density

I'm still having some trouble understanding what Bias and Variance for a specific estimator actually are.

I'm working with the definition of Bias as it is found on Wikipedia:

[image: Bias of an estimator]

If we define kernel-density-estimates as

[image: Wikipedia definition of kernel density estimate]

But how can I apply this to kernel density estimation, or to be more exact Parzen Windows? Can someone at least give me an idea how the estimated density f_hat(x) relates to Bias (and Variance)?

Qualitative I can already tell, that a box-window containing the whole data space will have maximum bias and no variance as the estimated density will simply be the average of the whole training data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just figured it out myself. The parameter theta in the case of density estimation is .. drumroll... the density function f(x). So the bias is defined as

**Bias = E[f_hat(x)] - f(x)**

The E[f_hat(x)] term is the expected value or the *mean* of the window function. Calculating it involves a simple integral.

*f(x)* is the *true* density function of the data, which in reality is likely to be unknown.